# Adapt jQuery-File-Upload for user profile image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload

I want to adapt jquery-file-upload http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/  to use like user profile image uploader,

1- only upload one image - you can restrict whit: maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
   but when try to add another image it lets you do that and show: Error Maximum number of files exceeded

2- edit image - upload another image and replace the preview

or please suggest another plugin to accomplish user profile image upload, regards.

Comment: whit the demo html and
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
                                            url: '/admin/upload_image/',
                                            maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
                                            autoUpload:true
                                        });

Comment: @TusharGupta how difficult can be adapt to something like this:
http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload

Comment: I'm here so far

.bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) { 
    var d = data;
    var src = d._response.result.files[0].thumbnailUrl;
    $("#preview-company-img").attr("src",src);
    setTimeout(function(){$( "[data-type='DELETE']" .click();},500);                                                
 });

whit another preview image <img id="preview-company-img"/>
I'm trying to reset the files to 0 so always upload only one also hide the template <tr style="display:none" class="template-download fade"> to prevent the flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was taking a bad approach, jquery-file upload allows you to send extra fields in this case user id so an independ form only to upload the image every time it select one autoUpload:true remove the normal preview list and make custom preview on fileuploaddone for only one image.